# Overflow : hidden in FF

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

I'm having a problem with overflow : hidden content, but only in FF.
[image]

I have two divs (each side of the vertical arrow, see above) each have overflow:hidden applied masking their respective child div. 
The child elements are being rotated onscroll event via jQuery.
For whatever reason the background image in each of the children elements are not being masked as they should by their parent div.

To see this inconsistency;
http://www.pearman.com.au/

Whats strange is the child content appears when inspecting any of the parents CSS properties in Firebug.

edit : find the CSS / HTML / JQuery

This code is run each time the onscroll is updated (alot);

```
    scrollAnimations.push({ 'start': 0, 'end': 450,
                'callback': function(scrollTop,scrollDirection){ 
                    ran_one.css({
                        '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+ -(scrollTop)*0.4 +'deg)',
                        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+ -(scrollTop)*0.4 +'deg)',
                        '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+ -(scrollTop)*0.4 +'deg)',
                        '-o-transform': 'rotate('+ -(scrollTop)*0.4 +'deg)',
                        'transform': 'rotate('+ -(scrollTop)*0.4 +'deg)' })
                    }
                });
            scrollAnimations.push({ 'start': 0, 'end': 900,
                'callback': function(scrollTop,scrollDirection){
                    ran_two.css({
                        '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+ -(scrollTop)*0.4 +'deg)',
                        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+ -(scrollTop)*0.4 +'deg)',
                        '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+ -(scrollTop)*0.4 +'deg)',
                        '-o-transform': 'rotate('+ -(scrollTop)*0.4 +'deg)',
                        'transform': 'rotate('+ -(scrollTop)*0.4 +'deg)' })
                    }
                });
```

CSS ;

```
#rainbow-mask-right{
        width:421px;
        height:421px;
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left: 50%;
        overflow:hidden;
        }
    #rainbow-mask-left{
        width:421px;
        height:421px;
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left: 50%;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin-left: -420px;
        visibility:visible;
        }
    #ran-one{
        background:url(images/home/rainbow/ran-dash.gif) no-repeat;
        width:421px;
        height:421px;
        display:block;
        top: 421px;
        position: absolute;

        transform: rotate(50deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(50deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -moz-transform: rotate(50deg); /* Firefox */
        -o-transform: rotate(50deg); /* Opera */
        }
    #ran-two{
        background:url(images/home/rainbow/ran-colour.gif) no-repeat transparent;
        width:421px;
        height:421px;
        display:block;
        top: 421px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 421px;
        }
   .set-origin {
    transform-origin:0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0; /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform-origin:0 0; /* Firefox */
    -o-transform-origin:0 0; /* Opera */
    }
```

and HTML

```
<div id='rainbow-mask-right'><div id='ran-one' class="set-origin"></div></div>
<div id='rainbow-mask-left'> <div id='ran-two' class="set-origin"></div></div>
```

Comment: Congrats for the site! :D

Comment: That's some fancy shootin' on that site! Hmm, just activating Firebug in FF makes the rainbow show up for me. On an aside the text fields on your contact form aren't clearing when you click in to them.

Comment: It probably won't be it, but it won't harm to try: `#home { text-align: left; }`. It works when adding it in Firebug, but since changing some styles in Firebug might make the rainbow appear... I know, it doesn't make sense, but I removed the `text-align: center;` from the `body` styles and the rainbow appeared :P That's definitely strange.

Comment: That site is great! I've never seen anything like it - very creative.

Comment: I see the same behaviour as @BillyMoat, but it only becomes visible if I inspect the actual element, not if I just turn on firebug.

Comment: Thanks guys!  yeah its really strange. I've tried to replicate turning overflow:hidden / visible with jQuery.   $('#rainbow-mask-left').delay(100).css({'overflow':'visible'}).css({'overflow':'hidden'});    but no luck.

Comment: @Cam That won't work as the browser will first let the script run, collect the changes and only redraw when the script's idle again. You'll probably need a small delay between the two style changes and hope the browser redraws the element during that time.

Comment: I tried this - $('#rainbow-mask-left').css({'overflow':'visible'}).delay(500).css({'overflow':'‌​hidden'});  as well as the setTimeOut equivalent. both failed to apply 'overflow':'hidden' after the delay..

Comment: Could you please provide some CSS and HTML as well.  Maybe your rainbow-mask-left element needs a set width and height,  you can find out by seeing if firebug actually highlights the element.

Comment: After messing around on firebug. I clicked on the rainbow mask left, disabled the boverflow hidden, and put it back and it started work as expected? My suggestion would be to set the style within the div element (style="overflow:hidden; backorund-position:;") and revise your javascript perhaps?

Comment: awesome website design. Impressed muchly that it works well in IE.

Comment: Not that this will solve it but can you start the ran_two animation a little bit later? I don't think it needs to start at 0. It should be easier to debug then. Let's say 210px? => ln.171:
scrollAnimations.push({ 'start': 210, 'end': 900

Comment: Once you get passed the 900 and scroll up, it's gone again ... weird

Comment: I know this is breaking the comment rules, but awesome site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after a little while of debugging, I am pretty sure I found the issue.

Looks like FireFox does not like to display empty containers. I am on 13.1, but after editing your HTML via FireBug, here is the end result:

[image: space enter]

Just add a simple

```
&nbsp;
```

to the rainbows and it should be a win.

Great looking site! Enjoy,

```
<div id="rainbow-mask-right"><div id="ran-one" class="set-origin">&nbsp;</div></div>
<div id="rainbow-mask-left"><div id="ran-two" class="set-origin">&nbsp;</div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks CrazyVipa!! you nailed it.

Comment: I couldn't let this go, have to ask if anyone can test. Can someone test without the spaces in FireFox 3-10? I think this is actually a new issue. I just received a few trouble tickets from work complaining that certain portions of the site were broke. These areas have not been touched in a while... and its all FireFox 13 users. Maybe something changed dramatically?? Anyone?